# How to disable usage of built-in functions in Eigen (which define which instruction to pikc for that architecture)

Tags: gcc, architecture, eigen3

I am working on Eigen test suite and i notice too many built-in functions which directly specify the exact instruction to be used for that particular architecture instead of giving freedom to the compiler to decide which is the best instruction for that source code. Can anyone help me how i can disable the use of built-ins with Eigen?

Answer (score 1):

To disable explicit vectorization and see what the compiler does with auto-vectorization, you can compile with `-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE`.
I also recommend compiling with `-DNDEBUG` (once you are sure your code is functionally correct). And sometimes `-ffast-math` or at least `-fassociative-math` may help the compiler finding better optimization opportunities.

While auto-vectorization is certainly getting better, I would not expect anything magic, though ([always compare the generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/JRh9v4) -- and benchmark!)

Also, compilers are not strictly bound to use the instructions corresponding to the used intrinsics, if they find functionally equivalent instructions:
https://godbolt.org/g/bEJNXZ

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! I am using the gcc compiler (latest release version) and i notice it is using only the intrinsics and Eigen heavily uses vector scalar instrinsics for Power platform. Is there any switch that would tell the compiler to not use the intrinsics in the eigen code?